# Consuming imports for JavaDoc in package-info.java

Tags: java, javadoc

In the JavaDoc for a package I'm documenting (specifically, within a package-info.java file), I have a number of lines that look like `{@link some.really.long.module.ClassName}`, and naturally I'd like to just import ClassName and say `{@link ClassName}` instead, but nothing I've tried works.  Is this even possible?

I've tried putting the imports above the package declaration and JavaDoc, but that shows a syntax error.  I've tried putting the imports below the package declaration and JavaDoc, but then the JavaDoc process warns `Tag @link: reference not found: ClassName`.

Comment: Exceptions are thrown. Compilation errors are shown.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
This class {@linkplain some.really.long.module.ClassName ClassName} does bla bla bla...
```

This will show as

> This class [ClassName](http://ClassName) does bla bla bla...

Answer (score 0):

Just use the fully qualified name in package-info documentation. JavaDoc will generate HTML without showing the fully qualified name (at least in 1.7), so the results should look fine. It's just more annoying to type.